# Calculation on pixel values and typecasting c#

Tags: c#

Below are 84 values that is the input for ColFWHM function. Based on this value, the function calculates one single value. But, for some reason, I am getting "0" for the Result. I think it is a problem with typecasting between float/ double somewhere, cant figure out where. Any advise to solve this is appreciated.

**data** -

```
    double[] datay ={0.0431373, 0.0470588, 0.054902, 0.0627451, 0.0745098, 0.0862745, 0.109804, 0.133333, 0.156863, 0.192157, 0.227451, 0.254902, 0.270588, 0.294118, 0.309804, 0.321569, 0.333333, 0.333333, 0.32549, 0.32549, 0.317647, 0.301961, 0.282353, 0.254902, 0.227451, 0.2, 0.176471, 0.152941, 0.129412, 0.113725, 0.0941176, 0.0784314, 0.0627451, 0.0470588, 0.0392157, 0.0352941, 0.027451, 0.0235294, 0.0196078, 0.0156863, 0.0156863, 0.0117647, 0.00784314, 0.00784314, 0.00784314, 0.00392157, 0.00392157, 0.00392157, 0.00392157, 0.00784314, 0.00392157, 0.00392157, 0.00392157, 0.00392157, 0.00392157, 0.00392157, 0.00392157, 0.00392157, 0.00392157, 0.00392157, 0.00392157, 0.00392157, 0.00392157, 0.00392157, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.00392157, 0.00392157, 0.00392157, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.00392157, 0.00392157, 0.00392157, 0.00392157, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.00392157};
```

**ColFWHM**

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Input: 1D array; Return: FWHM value.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="data"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static double ColFWHM(double[] data) 
    {
        //double[] datax;
        //double[] datay;
        //Console.WriteLine(data.Length);
        int L;
        int Mag = 4;
        double PP = 2.2;
        int CI = 0;
        //int y;
        double Interp;
        double Tlead;
        double Ttrail;
        double fwhm = 0;
        L = data.Length;
        double[] datay = new double[data.Length];
        double max = data.Max();
        CI = data.ToList().IndexOf(max);//Push index of peak to CI
        Console.WriteLine("CI :" + CI);

        //Create datay and normalize to max[data]
        for (int f = 0; f < data.Length; f++)
        {
            datay[f] = data[f]/max;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("datay[] Length :" + datay.Length);

        //create datax
        int[] datax = new int[data.Length];
        // Create datax as index for the number of elemts in data from 1-Length(data).
        for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)//[0,1,2]
        {
            datax[i] = (i + 1);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("datax[] Length :" + datax.Length);
        //Console.WriteLine(datax.GetValue);

        // Start to search lead
        int k = 2;
        while (Math.Sign(datay[k] - 0.5) == Math.Sign(datay[k - 1] - 0.5))
        {
            k = k + 1;
            //Console.WriteLine("K:"+k);
        }
        Interp = (0.5 - datay[k - 1]) / (datay[k] - datay[k - 1]);
        Console.WriteLine("Interp" + Interp);

        Tlead = datax[k - 1] + Interp * (datax[k] - datax[k - 1]);
        Console.WriteLine("Tlead" + Tlead);


        CI = CI + 1;

        // Start search for the trail
        while (Math.Sign(datay[k] - 0.5) == Math.Sign(datay[k - 1] - 0.5) && (k <= L - 1))// less than
        {
            k = k + 1;
        }
        if (k != L)
        {
            Interp = (0.5 - datay[k - 1]) / (datay[k] - datay[k - 1]);
            Ttrail = datax[k - 1] + Interp * (datax[k] - datax[k - 1]);
            Console.WriteLine("Ttrail" + Ttrail);

            fwhm = ((Ttrail - Tlead) / Mag) * PP;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("FWHM: " + fwhm);

        return fwhm;
    }//end main
```

Comment: This is waaaaay too much code, I don't think that someone actually will go through that and figure out what is wrong. Please try to narrow the problem down first instead of posting the whole classes

Comment: Is it narrowed down now ? added a minimal working example type  question.

Comment: is this true? `k != L`?

Comment: Yes that condition is true in this example data at-least.

Comment: we don't even know what this function is supposed to do. your variable names are hard to read/understand. have you run this through a debugger?

Comment: Have you even tried running your code? In your double array (which can't be cast to a float array) there are two `0.` entries which are invalid and need something after the decimal point.

Comment: Yes its absolutely fine through debugger, the function takes an Array of double values as shown and calculates the FWHM (full width at half the maximum) for that array. Which means, Finds the peak; finds the points that is 50% of peak and calculates the distance between them in terms of pixels, PP and Mag are just to convert that value to Microns.

Comment: @Logan : Yes I observed that, and changed it to double as you can see, now it takes in Double Array and returns the calculated Double value.

Comment: You still have incorrect value of `0.` in your `data` array. Should this be `0.0` I assume?

Comment: I dont see a value of 0 in the data array, but yes it should 0.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do a search here for your "lead":

```
int k = 2;
while (Math.Sign(datay[k] - 0.5) == Math.Sign(datay[k - 1] - 0.5))
{
  k = k + 1;
  //Console.WriteLine("K:"+k);
}
```

Then later you do exactly the same search for the trail:

```
// Start search for the trail
while ((Math.Sign(datay[k] - 0.5) == Math.Sign(datay[k - 1] - 0.5)) && (k <= L - 1))// less than
{
  k = k + 1;
}
```

This search seems redundant to me because you haven't reset the value of `k` anywhere, so it will never actually loop because it satisfied the condition to break out the loop in the first search.

This means that your `Ttrail` and `Tlead` are the same, so your end result is calculated as `(9.2777667641639709 - 9.2777667641639709) / Mag * PP` which will always be zero.

Even resetting your `k` to 2 will cause exactly the same behaviour as your first search, winding up with the same result.

Comment: It shouldn't be "CI = CI + 1;" it' s supposed to be "k = CI + 1;".

Comment: Are you using an IDE? I found this pretty quickly just by stepping through the code in Visual Studio.

Comment: @Logan me too. Once I'd cleaned up the input data it took 1 breakpoint to see what values were leading to the zero return value. You got to the underlying cause way ahead of me though. Perhaps the OP doesn't understand break points.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% certain what your algorithm is for, so I'm not going to comment on its implementation.

However, the reason why your method is returning 0 is this line:

```
fwhm = ((Ttrail - Tlead) / Mag) * PP;
```

For your sample data, at this point in the code `Ttrail - Tlead` is zero. Both variables are `9.2777667641639709`.

That's why `fwhm` is zero.